# Python Scope Confusion

Tags: python, numpy, scope, global, local

The idea here is to square the matrix n times and after each loop of squaring normalizing it. 
I guess the error is in the `final_matrix`-function and has to do with scope. I know this is horrible code, but I'm kind of new. So critique is more than welcome:)
Thanks a lit in advance!!

```
def normalize(F):
    row_sums = F.sum(axis = 1)
    new_matrix = F / row_sums[:, np.newaxis]
    return new_matrix

#square matrix
def square(F):
    F = F.dot(F)
    return F

#calculate final matrix
def final_matrix(M, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        F = square(F) 
        N = normalize(F)
    print(N)

x = final_matrix(M,n)
print(x)
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong?

Comment: No error data, no input data and expected output data. So this is just a typo ==> close request. Given answer is maybe accurate but won't help community.

Comment: i could give the whole code, but as I guessed the error was in the scope of the variables the one function I dind't think there is need of any more code. But probably you are right. I'll review this and come back with better info

Comment: We don't want the whole code.  But we do like enough to actually run a test case.  But in this case we can read the code, and see things like the use `F` where `M` would be more logical.  Inside `final_matrix` how is `F` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote 'F' instead of 'M'. Try this and see if this works

```
def normalize(F):
    row_sums = F.sum(axis = 1)
    new_matrix = F / row_sums[:, np.newaxis]
    return new_matrix

#square matrix
def square(F):
    F = F.dot(F)
    return F

#calculate final matrix
def final_matrix(M, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        # Your error was here. You had written 'F' instead of 'M' in the line below
        F = square(M) 
        N = normalize(F)
    print(N)

x = final_matrix(M,n)
print(x)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer:)! I'll see if i get it run in my code